# Simple way to array to strin conversion

Tags: php, arrays, string, laravel-5

I need to convert the laravel form validation error array to a string only the values.
I do not want use json_encode.

[image]

in my case I am trying to do the save edit function with ajax.
so I decided to get the form validation errors as a string from the controller.

writing a call back function to convert the array of errors to a string, so the error key may change form to form. how do I do this.

Is there a better way to handle this situation..

This is what I tried

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
    $error =  $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray();
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($error); echo '</pre>';
    $error_str = '';
    foreach ($error as $row){
       $error_str .= $row[0].'</br>';
    }
    echo $error_str;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `$row[0]`because it will only fetch first error from a list of errors of specific field.
Here is a solution to get all errors in one string with its field name.

```
    $str =  implode("\n", 
        array_map( function( $e, $key ){
            return $key.": ". implode(", ",$e);
        }, $error, array_keys($error) )
    );
    print_r($str);
```